# What's the proper way to fork a deb file?

Tags: package-management, application-development, deb

I downloaded the source code of a package using `apt-get source`, and changed it mostly for my own use. But then how do I manage the forked project?

I have no problem if it is just a deb file. But official deb files usually use debhelper, which has a lot of unwanted features.

To be specific, ideally, I wanted a way that:

- I can use a version control system such as `git`. Things such as the `.git` folder shouldn't be packaged into the source or binary package.
- I can easily apply upstream updates (from both the developer and packager) and do automerge or 3-way comparison. The normal diff between versions should also work as intended. I mean I should be able to compare a single source file, not the patches generated using quilt.
- It works reasonably for debugging. For example, preferably there should be an intuitive way to rebuild a single file using `make`, if `make` is used in the original project. And I should be able to build `.deb` files in fast ways, without copying too many files, rebuilding the whole project or messing up the workspace.

Comment: Use a ppa in launchpad.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How does that help for any of the 3 problems?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. LP is the preferred method for what you ask, although some of what you ask is not managed in any single standard way.  Your question is all over the map from coordinating with upstream (you should contact them directly) to packaging to version control to running make.